# Error Creating AssociatedTokenAccount when the signer/funder is one of the seeds. Any way around this?

Tags: spl-token, pda, associated-token-account

Im getting this error "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction"
I think its because Im passing in the same account twice one as signer and the other time as one of the seeds for the associated account. Is there any way to make it work?

```
 public static TransactionInstruction createAssociatedTokenAccount(PublicKey funder, PublicKey receiver) throws Exception {
        PublicKey.ProgramDerivedAddress assoc = getAssociatedTokenAddress(receiver,funder);
        byte[]b= new byte[Integer.valueOf(0).byteValue()];
        PublicKey assocTokenProgram=new PublicKey("ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL");

        List<AccountMeta> metas= new ArrayList<>();
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(funder,true,true));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(assoc.getAddress(),false,true));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(receiver,false,false));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(funder,false,false));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(SystemProgram.PROGRAM_ID,false,false));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(new PublicKey(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),false,false));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(Sysvar.SYSVAR_RENT_ADDRESS,false,false));
        TransactionInstruction instruction= new TransactionInstruction(assocTokenProgram,metas,b);
        return instruction;


    }
```

Comment: Kindly include your code. Difficult to give an helpful solution without it

Comment: @Ademola I included the code. This code works when the funder/signer is not passed in as one of the accounts to be used to create the associated account

Answer (score 2):

The fourth account provided must be the mint, and not the funder.  So instead, you should do:

```
        List<AccountMeta> metas= new ArrayList<>();
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(funder,true,true));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(assoc.getAddress(),false,true));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(receiver,false,false));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(mint,false,false));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(SystemProgram.PROGRAM_ID,false,false));
        metas.add(new AccountMeta(new PublicKey(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),false,false));
        TransactionInstruction instruction= new TransactionInstruction(assocTokenProgram,metas,b);
```

You also don't need the rent, so I omitted it.

Here's the reference JS implementation: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/c5a6d0ae31e9b651d3255340f85853bb7d166283/token/js/src/instructions/associatedTokenAccount.ts#L80

Comment: I've realized now that the SystemProgram.createAccountWithSeed is more suitable for my use case than a PDA your answer is correct tho